# Python Lambda Function Breaking with no Errors Logged in CloudWatch

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, pydub

I'm creating a Lambda function in Python which is triggered by uploading an MP3 file to my S3 bucket. The function (which works on my local machine) is supposed to use pydub to create a waveform from the audio, however, I've run into an issue I don't know how to solve.

It seems I'm able to save the file to the `/tmp` folder, but when I try to pass the file to `AudioSegment.from_file(filename)`, the function ends and there are no error logs in CloudWatch.

Here's the relevant block of code:

```
s3.download_file(bucket_name, file_key, '/tmp/temp.mp3')
src = "/tmp/temp.mp3"
try:
    print 'trying...'
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(src)
except:
    print 'its breaking'
print 'it worked'
```

I've wrapped the problem line in a `try` block to simplify the issue. CloudWatch simply logs:

```
START RequestId: 23af8832-061b-4c46-a226-6591bb972b5e Version: $LATEST
trying...
END RequestId: 23af8832-061b-4c46-a226-6591bb972b5e
```

Expected output would be:

```
START RequestId: 23af8832-061b-4c46-a226-6591bb972b5e Version: $LATEST
trying...
its breaking || it worked
END RequestId: 23af8832-061b-4c46-a226-6591bb972b5e
```

Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: How could there possibly be any error logged?  You are *explicitly* throwing away  all information about errors.

Comment: Right, well before I added the try block there were no errors logged, and with the try/except block, I would expect the next line in the logs to be either "it's breaking" or "it worked".

Answer (score 5):

Oh my goodness, so if anyone else gets stuck on this here's what solved it for me. The function wat timing out... I had no idea this was happening!

Find the `Basic Settings` block in your function configuration tab and increase the timeout.

I found the timeout error by manually creating a request and running a test from within the Lambda console.

Comment: That is soo nasty!! I spent an hour debugging my code before I found this out.  You are a legend... SMH, why CloudWatch doesnt put error "TIMEOUT" is beyond me!

Comment: It does, you get a message like:- "Task timed out after <timeout specified>"

Answer (score 1):

You can verify if your lambda is timing out via the AWS web console if you go to CloudWatch -> Logs -> Log Insights -> *select your desired log groups* -> *paste the following query* -> click `Run Query`:

```
fields @timestamp, @requestId, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like "Task timed out"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

The results are all log streams from timed out tasks in your log group, which in this case has your lambda logs.

Where I found this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-verify-invocation-timeouts/